# Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double' - error keeps popping up unsure as to the solution

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

func BMIcalc (weight: Int, height: Int) -> Int {

    let BMI = weight/height

    if BMI > 25 {
        print ("you are overweight")
    }

    else if BMI > 18.5 && BMI < 25 {
        print("you are normal weight")

    else
    }

    return BMI
}

print (BMIcalc(weight: 60, height: 180))
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare an `Int` and a `Double`, which you are trying to do, since `BMI` is of type `Int` while the numeric literal `18.5` is of type `Double`. Since `BMI` is a not an integer, you should declare it as a `Double`. To get the correct result for the division, you also need to convert `weight` and `height` to `Double` or even better declare the input arguments as `Double`, especially since both are expected to be non integers.

Btw your maths is also flawed, since BMI = weight / height ^ 2, where weight is in kilograms and height is in meters, so I've also fixed that part of your code.

```
func BMIcalc(weight: Double, height: Double) -> Double {
    let BMI = weight/(height*height)

    if BMI > 25 {
        print ("you are overweight")
    }
    else if BMI > 18.5 && BMI < 25 {
        print("you are normal weight")
    }
    else {
    }

    return BMI
}

print (BMIcalc(weight: 60, height: 1.80)) // 18.5185185185185
```

Comment: @MartinR you're absolutely correct, I remembered incorrectly, but fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

BMI is an `Int` and you are comparing it to a `Double`:
 `BMI > 18.5`.

Cast it to get the division right or work directly with type `Double`:

`func BMIcalc (weight: Double, height: Double) -> Double {`